# Color from database

Tags: php, mysql

And I want to users can change color for his usernames. And I want to write this colors in database. So there is my input code for message, but color didn't work, what is a wrong?

I created a column in my db.

Chat is working fine, but this code for color didn't work, and this code for delete old message didn't work either.

Edit: Oh I created a column color in the wrong table.

```
   <?php
session_start();
$uname = $_SESSION['username'];
$msg = $_REQUEST['msg'];

$con = mysql_connect('fdb13.biz.nf','18213213wqeqwed_chat','mewqe132131dddd1');
mysql_select_db('1846946_chat',$con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO logs (username,msg) VALUES ('$uname','$msg')");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
$resultc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM korisnici ORDER by color DESC");

while(($extract = mysql_fetch_array($result))||($extractc = mysql_fetch_array($resultc)) ){
        echo "<span style='color:" . $extractc['color'] . ";' class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span> <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
    }
?>
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs username");
if($result2==3){
mysql_query("DELETE FROM logs");
      }
?>
```

Comment: Is the missing `'` in your mysql_connect call in your original code?

Comment: tell us the error u are getting and i didnt get the line `mysql_query("DELETE FROM logs");`

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: I dont have a error..

Comment: Could you show me your table structures and the html result of your php code?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/wu2uo3t8x/

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/s5iot56gp/

Comment: @Kiriyaga I just saw your edit, does this mean the problem is solved? If not, can you try using Chrome's or Firefox's debugger and use "Inspect element" on the span element, then look at the styles that are applied. Is the color maybe being overwritten? Does the HTML look ok? Maybe you are forgetting the `#` before the color code?

Comment: Problem is not solved.HTML code look ok,i add # in my database.

Comment: Can you show us how the HTML output looks?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/qasipjw8p/

Comment: So he cant find color from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an `OR` (`||`) condition in your `while` statement. It would only loop over one of the 2 resultqueries, not both. You can make 2 separate while loops and save the resultquery in an array instead:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs ORDER by id DESC");
$resultc = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM korisnici ORDER by color DESC");

$resultArray = [];
$resultcArray = [];

// Put your results in an array
while( $extract = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
     $resultArray[] = $extract;
}
while( $extractc = mysql_fetch_array($resultc) ){
     $resultcArray[] = $extract;
}

// Now loop over (one of) the arrays
for( $i = 0; $i < $resultArray; $i++ ) {
     echo "<span style='color:" . $resultcArray[$i]['color'] . ";' class='uname'>" . $resultArray[$i]['username'] . "</span> <span class='msg'>" . $resultArray[$i]['msg'] . "</span><br>";
}
```

However, this will most likely not give you the wanted results, because the arrays will not have the same length + they are not coupled to eachother. You will need to use a [JOIN](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/) sql query instead of 2 SELECTs.

So something like:

```
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs 
                       INNER JOIN korisnici 
                       ON logs.username = korisnici.username 
                       ORDER by logs.id, color DESC");
// You will need 2 columns with the same value to couple them to eachother, I took username as example  

while( $extract = mysql_fetch_array($results) ){
    echo "<span style='color:" . $extract['color'] . ";' class='uname'>" . $extract['username'] . "</span> <span class='msg'>" . $extract['msg'] . "</span><br>";
}
```

Comment: This give me a error.Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /srv/disk6/1846946/www/maturskichat.co.nf/logs.php on line 11

Comment: @Kiriyaga That error message is very clear. Have you tried solving it by yourself yet?

Comment: @ Dark Ashelin so $results need to be true,but i dont know how to solve this.

Comment: @Kiriyaga No it doesn't need to be true. If it is `false`, you either made a mistake in your code, or the SQL query is giving 0 rows as result. If you just copy-pasted the `INNER JOIN` SQL from my answer, it will probably not work right away. You need to make it work by editing your tables. Read my commentation in the code and the [Documentation link](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Comment: OHH i created this site on free hosting and i cant add foreign key,becouse my tabe use myISAM engine.What i can do?

Comment: @Kiriyaga Perhaps you can use a SELECT query like this: `SELECT * FROM logs, korisnici WHERE logs.username = korisnici.username`

Comment: qUERY like this didnt work...

Comment: @Kiriyaga I'm sorry but "didn't work" really does not give any information to me. I cannot solve your issue with 0 information. Please at least give us the error message or what the unexpected behaviour is.

Comment: This give me error like this:

Comment: Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /srv/disk6/1846946/www/maturskichat.co.nf/logs.php

Comment: my query :mysql_query("SELECT * FROM (logs,korisnici) WHERE logs.username = korisnici.username ORDER by logs.id,korisnici.color DESC");

Comment: Well you don't need the `()` around your tablenames. Also, do you have the column `username` in both tables? Do they also both contain matching data?

Comment: Now its working but dont have color..Here is my inspect element:http://postimg.org/image/5s2koecbz/

Comment: Now and color is working.TYYYYY Dark Ahelin.But now my messaeges was writed on bottom.How to fix that?

Comment: @Kiriyaga If your question was resolved, please mark an answer as accepted. If you have any other issues please first try to solve them by yourself (usually you are able to find out what the problem is by googling the "symptoms") and if you really can't find it, open another question.